# Why are the object values getting pushed into the array 3 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, amazon-s3

I have a simple object array into which I am pushing an object with 2 fields: bucketName and Date. The problem is that the values are getting pushed thrice into the array. Please help me.

JS:

```
sortBucket: function(bucketList) {
    var counter, j = 0;
    var str = "aws-billing-csv";
    console.log("Bucket List :: ", bucketList);

    bucketList.forEach(function(bucket, index) {
        (function(bucketId) {
            var bucketObj = {};
            // console.log("Bucket Id :: ",bucketId);
            s3Client.listObjects(params = {Bucket: bucketId }, function(err, data) {
                var csvBucketArr = [];
                if (err) {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Could not load objects from ' + bucketID;
                }
                else{        
                    //console.log("Bucket Data "+index+" :: ",data);
                    data.Contents.forEach(function(content,contentIndex){
                        var fileKey = content.Key;
                        if(fileKey.search(str) != -1) {
                            // console.log("fileKey["+bucketId+"] "+contentIndex+" :: ",fileKey + "  Date :: " ,content.LastModified);
                            bucketObj[fileKey] = {
                                lastModified    : content.LastModified,
                                bucketName      : bucketId
                            }
                            if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(bucketObj)){
                                csvBucketArr.push(bucketObj);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    csv = csvBucketArr;
                  }
                  if(csvBucketArr.length!==0)
                      console.log("csvBucketArr :: ",csvBucketArr));
                  });
             }(bucket.bucketName));
            // console.log("Bucket " + index + " :: ", bucket);
          });
       },
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint at `csvBucketArr.push(bucketObj);` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the same object into the array in each iteration of:

```
data.Contents.forEach(function(content,contentIndex){...});
```

So, as many times as that `.forEach()` loop iterates, you end up pushing the exact same `bucketObj` object into the `csvBucketArr` array.

If you want each iteration of that `.forEach()` to put a new and different `bucketObj` object into the array, then you need to create a new object each time inside that loop like this:

```
sortBucket: function(bucketList) {
    var counter, j = 0;
    var str = "aws-billing-csv";
    console.log("Bucket List :: ", bucketList);

    bucketList.forEach(function(bucket, index) {
        (function(bucketId) {
            // console.log("Bucket Id :: ",bucketId);
            s3Client.listObjects(params = {Bucket: bucketId }, function(err, data) {
                var csvBucketArr = [];
                if (err) {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Could not load objects from ' + bucketID;
                }
                else{        
                    //console.log("Bucket Data "+index+" :: ",data);
                    data.Contents.forEach(function(content,contentIndex){
                        // ===> create new bucketObj object
                        var bucketObj = {};
                        var fileKey = content.Key;
                        if(fileKey.search(str) != -1) {
                            // console.log("fileKey["+bucketId+"] "+contentIndex+" :: ",fileKey + "  Date :: " ,content.LastModified);
                            bucketObj[fileKey] = {
                                lastModified    : content.LastModified,
                                bucketName      : bucketId
                            }
                            if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(bucketObj)){
                                csvBucketArr.push(bucketObj);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    csv = csvBucketArr;
                  }
                  if(csvBucketArr.length!==0)
                      console.log("csvBucketArr :: ",csvBucketArr));
                  });
             }(bucket.bucketName));
            // console.log("Bucket " + index + " :: ", bucket);
          });
       },
```